# Убрать степень e+10

Tags: php

столкнулся с проблемой.
Как мне преобразовать число 
`1.0E+4` в число `1000`?
PHP сам делает число таким через степень, уже всю голову сломал
Это из математики:
`1.0E+4 = 1.0 * 10^4 = 1.0 * 1000 = 1000`

Comment: 10^4 == 1000? Откуда такая математика?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

максимально возможное цело число, т.е. [`integer`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php), определяется константой `PHP_INT_MAX`. Все, что больше, нативно может быть выражено только через числа с плавающей точкой.

Так же вы можете обратить внимание на библиотеку [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.gmp.php)

Comment: GMP отключена в основном везде, а так да. Только там вроде числа задаются не в научной этой нотации

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$d = 1.0E+4;
echo (int)sprintf("%d",$d);
echo $d ; //тоже 10000
echo number_format($d, 0, '', '');
?>
```

Вообще 4 нуля. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема появляется тогда когда это число длинее, например, 15 символов

Comment: Например измените 4 на 30

Comment: @igolka97, ну так в integer не влазит. 

   echo number_format($d, 0, '', '');

Потеря точности!